# Description of ideals of a polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomial-rings

$R$ is an integral domain then shows that an ideal $I$ of $R[X]$ is either principal or of the form $(f, r), r \in R$. The hint is to use the Gauss lemma.

I started by assuming that $I$ is not principal, then I want to consider $G= \{f \in I| f(0) = 0\}$, pick the element in it with minimal degree, I think that $G$ should be generated by this element. But the usual argument of division algorithm cannot go through here, because $R[X]$ is not Euclidean. How should I finish the proof?

$R$ should be assumed to be a PID.

Comment: This is obviously false for any integral domain $R$. I assume that $R$ is a **PID** (in this case, the claim is true) ?

Comment: Yes, $R$ should be a PID

Comment: @GreginGre:  are you ***asking*** if the claim is true (assuming $R$ is a PID), or ***affirming*** it is?

Comment: I know it is. I was just pointing out that there are counterexamples without this assumption.